# Each and First causing strange results

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

```
$('.fader').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('.slide').each(function(i){
        $(this).first().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Hello, for some reason this is adding .active to every '.slide' under the '.fader' not the first one. I want to use this multiple times through out the site so I want to avoid being absolute and that's my reasoning behind using the eaches.

When I alert (i) it counts to 3 which is the right count, I would expect it to go 0, 0, 0, 0 because of this but it doesn't.

```
<div class="container fader">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row slide">
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row slide">
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row slide">
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row slide">
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8"></div>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the HTML

Comment: *"I want to use this multiple times through out the site so I want to avoid being absolute and that's my reasoning behind using the eaches."* What would the second time do differently than the first time?

Comment: It wouldn't do anything different, but this functionality will used under a different section. So .fader could be called multiple times throughout the page. That's what I have a .fader on a each too.

Answer (score 5):

> Hello, for some reason this is adding .active to every '.slide' under the '.fader' not the first one....

Right. `$(this).first()` is a no-op, it's the same as `$(this)`. [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) takes the jQuery set and reduces it to the first (0th) element in that set. By definition, `$(this)` produces a set with a single element, so `.first()` has no effect on it.

It's not clear what your goal is.

Various possibilities:

1. If your goal is to add `.active` to the first `.slide` under `.fader` that doesn't *already* have `.active`, then: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/1/edit)):

   ```
   $(".fader .slide:not(.active):eq(0)").addClass("active");
   ```
2. If your goal is to move it from one slide to the next, then: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/2) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/2/edit))

   ```
   var active = $(".fader .active");
   if (active.length) {
     active = active.removeClass("active").next();
   }
   if (!active.length) {
     active = $(".fader .slide").first();
   }
   active.addClass("active");
   ```
3. If you literally want to just add it to the first slide, then: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/3) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/3/edit))

   ```
   $(".fader .slide").first().addClass("active");
   ```

   Or alternately:

   ```
   $(".fader .slide:first").addClass("active");
   ```
4. If you want to add it to the first (if missing) and remove it from all others (if present), then: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/4) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/4/edit)):

   ```
   $(".fader .slide")
       .first().addClass("active").end()
       .slice(1).removeClass("active");
   ```

I appear to have been a bit inconsistent above when using `:eq` vs. `:first`. For clarity: `:eq(0)` and `:first` are the same thing. Both are jQuery additions, and so require that jQuery not defer to the browser's built-in selection mechanism. In contrast, using a pure CSS selector to start with, then using the `.first()` *method*, lets jQuery use the browser's built-in selection system but then reduce the result to the desired subset.

---

In a comment you've said:

> I want to develop it like you would a jQuery plugin where all I have to do is add the class fader to the parent and slide to each of its children and it would become a slider. Of course because of this I need to make sure that I'm not being absolute with my selector, that every .fader gets looked at and .slide.

To do that, you just constrain yourself to working within each `.fader` element. Here's an example plugin that works on a jQuery set, making the given slide within the set active: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/5) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rosopozi/5/edit)):

```
// Plugin
(function($) {
  $.fn.slider = function(index) {
    // `this` here is the jQuery set; iterate over it
    this.each(function() {
      // `this` here is each DOM element in the set
      var slides = $(this).find(".slide");
      slides.removeClass("active");
      slides.eq(index).addClass("active");
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

// Use it to make the first slide in each
// fader active
$(".fader").slider(0);
```

`slider` is probably the wrong name for the plugin, but you get the idea.

The key bit there is that we iterate (as you suspected) through the set of `.fader` elements, and within each iteration, we find the `.slide` elements *inside* the fader (using `.find`) and act on those.

Comment: Hi T.J, I apologise for the confusion. That is the HTML I pasted is the HTML that is being output, I want it to add .active to the first .slide.

Comment: @Tom: But several of them already have that class. Which one do you want to add it to?

Comment: I wanted to add .active to the first .slide, my code is adding it to every .slide as seen above.

Comment: @Tom: Then you want #3 above (if `active` is not on any of them to start with) or #4 (if it's on one but not the one you want).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure you are absolutely understand what I'm trying to achieve. Using ('.fader .slide') would select every ('.fader .slide') which is great, I can use a .first() on that, but if I use the .fader again later on in the page it wouldnt work because it's an absolute selector. I want to develop it like you would a jQuery plugin where all I have to do is add the class fader to the parent and slide to each of its children and it would become a slider. Of course because of this I need to make sure that I'm not being absolute with my selector, that every .fader gets looked at and .slide

Comment: @Tom: (You're welcome, btw.) Addressing that would require more context than you have in the question, but I've taken a stab at it above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fader').each(function(){
    $this = $(this).find('.slide');
    $this.removeClass('.active').fadeOut();
    $active = $this.first().addClass('.active').fadeIn();
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $active = $active.next();
        $this.removeClass('.active').fadeOut(function(){
            if($active.length == 0){ $active = $this.first().addClass('.active').fadeIn(); }
            $active.addClass('.active').fadeIn();
        });
    },5000);
});
```

I got it working, this is what I was looking for. Thanks though T.J